# Need to get specific Data in column via informatica

Tags: sql, informatica

How can I trim the values of column in informatica to the places we want, for example if I have a column name country with the data "IN-HR" then I need the values in target for the same column like "HR" only. So how can I trim the data in columns like that.

Comment: `trim()` has a specific meaning in databases -- to remove white space characters from the beginning and end of a string.  That does not seem to apply.  More sample data and desired results would clarify your question.

Comment: Actually informatica doesn't have a `trim()` function but the functionality can be achievable. However,I did not understand the question. can you pls elaborate with some examples?

Comment: @Koushik for eg : there is a column name country which have data as follows :

Comment: it seems some text is missing. could you pls update the question.

Comment: @Koushik so for example, if we have one column named as country and have data like : IN-HR then after processing we need the data for that country Column should be HR only and "IN-" should get trimmed

Comment: You can use replacestr `REPLACESTR ( CaseFlag, InputString, OldString1, [OldString2, ... OldStringN,] NewString )`. `REPLACESTR ( 1, INPUT_COL, 'IN-', '' )`.

Comment: You can use `REPLACE()` too - `REPLACE ( INPUT_COL, 'IN-', '' )`

Comment: But the problem is it Could be any country name CD in 2 digits and not specifically IN for ex it could be US or any other country, so in this case hardcode won't work, I need to know what I can do here so that whatever country code came we just remove it.